# Nested navigation with AutoRoute

Tags: flutter

I need to do nested navigation with AutoRoute and somthing that looks line bottomNavigation bar.

this is My AppRouter

```
AutoRoute(
  page: HomeScreenWidget,
  children: [
    AutoRoute(page: MapScreenWidget),
    AutoRoute(page: ChatScreenWidget),
    AutoRoute(page: UserProfileScreenWidget),
  ],
),
```

HomeScreen is initial screen with widget that looks like bottomNavigationBar in it,

this is HomeScreenWidget

```
class HomeScreenWidget extends ElementaryWidget<IHomeScreenWidgetModel> {
  HomeScreenWidget({
    Key? key,
    WidgetModelFactory wmFactory = defaultHomeScreenWidgetModelFactory,
  }) : super(wmFactory, key: key);

  final AppTextController controller = AppTextController();
  final AppRouter _router = AppRouter();
  @override
  Widget build(IHomeScreenWidgetModel wm) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _router.navigate(const ChatRoute()), child: const Text('chat')),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _router.navigate(const MapRoute()), child: const Text('map')),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _router.navigate(UserProfileRoute()), child: const Text('profile')),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Map, Chat, and profile widgets only have Text widget inside Center. First of all i need to make navigation

error that i got without AppRouter inside Expanded widget

```
E/flutter ( 5858): Looks like you're trying to navigate to a nested route without adding their parent to stack first
E/flutter ( 5858): try navigating to HomeRoute -> ChatRoute
```

if i try to use AutoRouter widget i got this error

```
'package:auto_route/src/matcher/route_matcher.dart':
package:auto_route/…/matcher/route_matcher.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 27 pos 12: 'this[key]?.children != null'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AutoRoute(page: EmptyRouterPage, name: 'RouterA', children: [
  AutoRoute(page: Page1, initial: true),
  AutoRoute(page: Page2),
]),
AutoRoute(page: EmptyRouterPage, name: 'RouterB', children: [
  AutoRoute(page: Page3, initial: true),
  AutoRoute(page: Page4),
]),
```

and you would like to programmatically navigate from say, `/RouterA/Page2` to `/RouterB/Page4`.

Here's how you can do it. First, you can pop to the root (`/`) and then navigate to the new route like below:

```
AutoRouter.of(context).popUntilRoot();
AutoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/RouterB/Page4');
```